# How to use streamFromFutures method dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method:

```
Stream<T> streamFromFutures<T>(Iterable<Future<T>> futures) async* {
  for(Future<T> future in futures){
    T result = await future;
    yield result;
  }
}
```

And I want do like -> `streamFromFutures(futures).listen((event) => print(event), onError: (error) => print('error $error'));`

Also I wrote method

```
Iterable<Future<T>> futures<T>(){
  //Iterable iterable = new Iterable.generate(5);

  return ?;
}
```

but what should I return?

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I just want to use streamFromFutures but I can't write function iterable list of futures with any type((

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `return iterable.map(
          (count) => Future<T>(() => T)`?

Comment: I'm learning more about stream and future. and I want to use the streamFromFuture function which takes Iterable<Future<T>>... and `return iterable.map( (count) => Future<T>(() => T)` is nothing.. I just want to write function which will generate a futures to parameters streamFromFutures<T>. I clearly explained?

Comment: `Future` returns some value (or error) - in your case: `Future<T>(() => T)` there is no value (nor error) - so what do you want to return?

Comment: my question is edited. I hope it will be so clearer

Comment: here you have the sample: `var iterable = Iterable.generate(5, (i) => Future(() => i * i)); Stream.fromFutures(iterable).listen(print);` - it prints `i*i` for `i` in [0..4]

Comment: So I guess in `Future(() => i * i))` instead `i * i` I can write any data? If so thank you.. I'm beginning to understand

Comment: yes, exactly, it returns `i^2` there and you can replace it with any value you like

Comment: Thank you pskink.. I couldn't realize those function 1.5 days. You helped me. If you want you can answer this question and so I will mark it.

Comment: i am glad it helped...